# Infinite loops with a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, infinite-loop

I'm working on a program that takes an input of numbers from `stdin` and computes the median of the sequence and prints it out as a `float`. I'm currently getting an infinite loop in the function

> len(struct node *)

at the for loop and I'm not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    float *val;
    struct node *next;
};

int len(struct node *list) {
    int i = 0;
    struct node *temp = list;
    for (i = 0; temp != NULL; i++) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return i;
}

float median(int size, struct node list) {
    struct node temp = list;
    int i = 0;
    if (size == 1) {
        return *temp.val;
    } else
    if (size == 2) {
        return (*(temp.val) + *(temp.next->val)) / 2;
    } else {
        if (size / 2 == 1) {
            for (i = 3; i != (size / 2) - 1; i++) {
                temp = *(temp.next);
            }
            return *temp.val;
        } else {
            for (i = 3; i != (size / 2); i++) {
                temp = *(temp.next);
            }
            return (*(temp.val) + *(temp.next->val)) / 2;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node *tmpnode;
    tmpnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmpnode->next = NULL;
    struct node *list = NULL;
    list = tmpnode;
    float temp = 0;
    int err = 0;
    int size = 0;
    while ((err = scanf("%f", &temp)) != EOF) {
        if (err < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: non-integer character inputted\n");
            return 1;
        }
        tmpnode->val = &temp;
        tmpnode->next = list;
        list = tmpnode;
    }
    size = len(list);
    if (size == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: no inputs found");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%f\n", median(size, *list));
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I've fixed the infinite loop, but now I'm getting a segfault at `temp = *(temp.next)` in `median()`. Do I need to allocate for `temp`?

Comment: You are using the same `tmpNode` for every iteration of the `while` loop. You need to allocated a new node each time.

Comment: You need to allocate a new node for each element you add to the list.  Otherwise you can only store one value, and you're creating a cyclic list with a single node in it.  Move the `malloc` call into the loop.

Comment: Ok that makes sense thank you!

Comment: That's right, move it there.  Just think it through:  If your list has 10 elements, then you need to call `malloc` 10 times, once per element.

Comment: @kaylum To create buffer for data, you should call `malloc()` one more time for each element.

Comment: I now get a segfault in `median()` when it attempts to iterate through the linked list. Do I need to allocate for `temp` in `malloc()`?

Comment: @MikeCAT You mean for `val`? If so, that doesn't relate directly to the infinete loop and that was what I was commenting on (it wasn't a comprehensive answer). And arguably a better approach than allocating val seperately is just to change its type to be a `float` instead of a pointer. There is not much benefit in allocating it seperately and has the downside of having to deal with more dynamic allocations and frees than is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created only one node and assigned `next` of the node to itself, so this is cause of the infinite loop.

Create new nodes and link them in the input loop.
Assigning address of `temp` to all nodes is also not good.

Your `main()` function should be like this:

```
int main(void){
    struct node *tmpnode;
    tmpnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(tmpnode == NULL){
        perror("malloc 1");
        return 1;
    }
    tmpnode->next = NULL;
    struct node *list = NULL;
    list = tmpnode;
    float temp = 0;
    int err = 0;
    int size = 0;
    while((err = scanf("%f", &temp)) != EOF){
        if(err < 1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: non-integer character inputted\n");
            return 1;
        }
        tmpnode->val = malloc(sizeof(float));
        if(tmpnode->val == NULL){
            perror("malloc 2");
            return 1;
        }
        *tmpnode->val = temp;
        tmpnode->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(tmpnode->next == NULL){
            perror("malloc 3");
            return 1;
        }
        tmpnode = tmpnode->next;
        tmpnode->val = NULL;
        tmpnode->next = NULL;
    }
    size = len(list);
    if(size == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: no inputs found");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%f\n", median(size, *list));
    /* code to free the list should be here */
    return 0;
}
```

(I gave input `1 2 3 4 5` and this program's output was `1.500000`, which might be wrong)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the median you would have to arrange the nodes in order and get the number that is in the middle.If the number of nods is even and there is no middle you should add the two middlemost numbers and divide them by two.

**Is the sequence in order? If not you're miscalculating the median.**

Supposing the sequence is in order.

I didn't really understand the usefulness of this statement

> if(size/2 == 1)

Maybe you're trying to see if the size is odd. In that case you should do:

```
>  if(size%2 == 1)
```

Why the list is probably looping might be due to this

```
 for(i = 3; i != (size/2); i++){
          temp = *(temp.next);
 }
```

Suppose you pass a 5 to the function size/2=2 (decimal part is lost), so it'll keep on going until an overflow occurs and it actually reaches 2, making your program most probably seg_fault in the process.

Start from i=0, because even though you started from 3 your current node is not the third one but the FIRST ONE.

Good luck hope this helps!!!!

Comment: Wow I didn't even realize that I forgot to sort the list. Thank you!

Comment: Edited a part of it though that the list was an array(stupid ), let me know if you need anymore help!!